# How do I fix the left mouse opening the menu instead of breaking blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I've already tried clicking and holding the left button of my mouse, and it just won't work! Whenever I press it, it opens the game menu instead.

Comment: Have you checked your controls in the options menu?

Answer (score 7):

Fixing this issue is quite simple. It is generally caused by modified keybinds (changing the controls). For some reason, mine seem to change "randomly" a lot, or maybe it is just my little siblings; anyway, here's how to fix it:

- Go to options (either in game or in the main menu) and select "controls"
- The first button is Button 1, AKA the left mouse button (generally used for breaking blocks)
- Ensure that button 1 is set to attack

If all else fails, I'd say you have set your mouse button to = escape some how. If you are using windows, I'd recommend checking out this page: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-vista/change-your-keyboard-layout to change your keyboard layout back to default.

Comment: +1 for the "or maybe it's just my siblings"

Answer (score 3):

On PC press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and click `Options`->`Controls`. See if your answer is in that menu.

If you are talking about mouse clicks. That is if you aren't and you are referring to a keyboard layout, then I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Check your keybinds: I had the same problem, it turned out while changing my sensitivity I accidentally changed Attack/Destroy to <kbd>E</kbd>